# php week(curdate()) sum of other years

Tags: php, mysql

OK so i have this query:

```
SELECT obrero as MAESTRO, sum(costo_semanal) AS TOTAL_COST,
            ROUND(SUM(week_cost)/MONTH(CURDATE()),2)  AS MONTHLY_COST,
            ROUND(SUM(week_cost)/WEEK(CURDATE()),2)   AS WEEKLY_COST
            from tbl_costos WHERE obrero ='$maestro'
```

I did this and it worked great in 2015, the problem is that now on 2016 we go back to week 1 and month 1 so im not having the proper division.

What I need to accomplish is to sum the 52 weeks of the past year and sum the current week of this year so i could have a % of the cost per week

"cost/number of weeks" = $cost per week.

for example of today 2016-01-18 being the 4th week of the year

total paid (of 2015 and 4 weeks of 2016) = $4000.00
weeks = 52 + 4 = 56

4000.00/56 = $71.4285714 average cost per week

The same thing applies to Months, it should be doing the division with 13, and cus January is month 1, its doing it over 1.

I could just do:

`SUM(week_cost)/(12+ MONTH(CURDATE()));`

and

`SUM(week_cost)/(52 + WEEK(CURDATE()));`

but that would solve the problem for this year only!!

Comment: How would the calculation look like in 2017?

Comment: You're assuming that every maestro started to generate data since 01-01-2015,  so you compute averages based on a 52 week year for all of them,  how about maestros who join later?  Weak week computes.

Comment: Yes weak week computes. But im new and learning. Thanks either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DATEDIFF() in order to calculate the number of days each maestro has worked from a given date, "start_date" to a given end date "end_date", and then convert those days to weeks, months and years if you need to.

Be flexible and anticipate that each maestro can work from any given date, or a report can be asked from any given date.  Your's assume that each maestro started to work on 2015-01-01 and that all reports shall be done with this in mind.  Reality is different.

```
Select obrero as MAESTRO, sum(costo_semanal) as TOTAL_COST, ROUND(SUM(costo_semanal/ROUND(DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date)/30,0)),0) AS MONTHLY_COST, ROUND(SUM(costo_semanal/ROUND(DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date)/7,0)),0) AS WEEKLY_COST FROM tbl_costos WHERE obrero=$maestro;
```

Do not place the variable $maestro on your query,  better use **PREPARED STATEMENTS**.

Comment: That would work but i should have a table that saves the starting date of the worker? And the end date of the worker?